# What is "__VIEWSTATE_KEY" hidden input field in a asp.net web form and what is it used for

Tags: c#, .net, iis, webforms

We use an asp.net application using web forms and viewing the page source there is a field generated as below

```
input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE_KEY" id="__VIEWSTATE_KEY" value="VIEWSTATE_xxooxx...."
```

Our company recently had a security scan run against our application with a flag raised for `Cross-Site Request Forgery`. The scan suggested it updated the value of this hidden field and did another post that resulted in a valid request. Is this a false positive test?

Answer (score 1):

ViewState is a feature of ASP.NET WebForm. It stores states of the ASP.NET WebForm Controls. The more web server controls that used by the page, the longer the ViewState will be.

You can basically ignore it. It's a false positive.

Answer (score 1):

The viewstate is the technique used by an ASP.NET Web page to persist changes to the state of a Web Form across postbacks. by default, placed in a hidden form field named __VIEWSTATE. So, as the name suggests, The  "__VIEWSTATE_KEY" is the name of viewstate.

More information about viewstate you can refer to this link:

[ASP.NET View State](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/ms972976(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)